# Apply operation and a division operation in the same step using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get proportion of nouns in my text using the code below and it is giving me an error. I am using a function that calculates the number of nouns in my text and I have the overall word count in a different column.

```
pos_family = {
    'noun' : ['NN','NNS','NNP','NNPS']
}

def check_pos_tag(x, flag):
    cnt = 0
    try:
        for tag,value in x.items():
            if tag in pos_family[flag]:
                cnt +=value
    except:
        pass
    return cnt

df2['noun_count'] = df2['PoS_Count'].apply(lambda x: check_pos_tag(x, 'noun')/df2['word_count'])
```

Note: I have used nltk package to get the counts by PoS tags and I have the counts in a dictionary in PoS_Count column in my dataframe.

If I remove "/df2['word_count']" in the first run and get the noun count and include it again and run, it works fine but if I run it for the first time I get the below error.

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 100, placement implies 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can we see some sample data for df2

Comment: Here is the sample data
 word_count PoS_Count
0 601 {'JJ': 65, 'NN': 117, 'VBG': 24, 'CD': 4}
1 201 {'JJ': 19, 'NN': 39, 'NNP': 6, 'VBZ': 1}
2 180 {'NN': 34, 'JJ': 15, 'RB': 5, 'VBD': 15}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have guessed, the problem is in the `/df2['word_count']` bit.

`df2['word_count']` is a pandas series, but you need to use a float or int here, because you are dividing `check_pos_tag(x, 'noun')` (which is an `int`) by it.

A possible solution is to extract the corresponding field from the series and use it in your lambda.

However, it would be easier (and arguably faster) to do each operation alone. 
Try this:

```
df2['noun_count'] = df2['PoS_Count'].apply(lambda x: check_pos_tag(x, 'noun')) / df2['word_count']
```

Comment: I knew I could get the desired result if I run the two calculations separately but thought of checking if there was a way to do it in one step.
Thank you! Your solution worked!